# Java based configuration, autowire bean with arguments

Tags: java, spring, swing, autowired, spring-annotations

This is the first time i'm trying to write a swing app with Spring(java based configuration only, i don't want XML). The problem is that i do not know how to autowire a bean that requires an argument, in my application i will be creating large amount of JPanel(and for them LineBorder etc.) and i'm struggling to find the correct way of how to do this. Should i just create a bean definition that will return a simple JButton, set scope to "prototype", autowire it and do all the initialization after in my GUI class?

Also in swing app, should a create everything using spring?(not a single "new" keyword outside of my configuration class), like when i have

```
linebuttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 70));
```

should i instead write a method returning a new Dimension bean like this?

```
Dimension d = context.getBean("dimension");
d.setSize(0, 70);
linebuttonPanel.setPreferredSize(d);
```

Or should i move the dimension initialization into the configuration class and write this

```
linebuttonPanel.setPreferredSize(context.getBean("dimension", 0, 70));
```

I was trying to use @Autowire wherever possible and this is the problem i encountered, here is first option where i need to somehow provide the argument while autowiring

[image]

Second option is to implement ApplicationContextAware and use getBean method but is this the right way of how to do this for every bean?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered the threading issues that you might encounter while mixing Spring & Swing? Swing requires you to respect its threading model (Event Dispatch Thread), and it might be quite difficult to control when delegating component creation to Spring. In our project, on the client side we only use Spring for implementing services called by Swing components, but we keep control over all components lifecycles. Not to say that it is impossible to achieve, but tutorials out there seem to completely overlook this.

Comment: Unfortunately, `@Autowared` does not support passing of parameters. So, your second approach is good enough, but one note: don't implement `ApplicationContextAware` interface. Just mark `ApplicationContext` property of your class with @Autowired annotation. This annotation made to simplify binding of objects, including implementation of all `Aware` interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an access to application context when you have to create your button.

You can autowire `ApplicationContext` into your bean and lookup for Button bean from there, BUT it's extremely BAD idea. You shouldn't inject entire application context into your particular bean, it breaks loose coupling idea the spring was designed for.

So you'd better remove `ApplicationContextAware` interface from your `GUI` class definition and delete `ApplicationContext applicationContext` class field as well.

In this case it's better to make bean creation operations `abstract` and implement them in java based app config.

I mean you can define abstract method

```
protected abstract JButton getButton(String name)
```

in your `GUI` class, so the class would become abstract as well.

Then you can make a bean definition in your current config as follows:

```
@Bean
public GUI gui() {
    return new GUI() {
        @Override
        protected JButton getButton(String name) {
            // note, here you're referencimg your Bean jButton of scope "prototype"
            return jButton(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i have a bean definition of JTextField with annotations @Bean and @Scope("prototype") and inside of it i'm creating and adding new KeyAdapter do i have to make a separate bean definition for that adapter which will be also marked as @Scope("prototype") and refer to it or is it enough to just write JTextField field = new JTextField(); field.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){}); ?

Comment: @Peter, in a nutshell, if you need to create many nested objects in your app, it would be difficult to do so with bean definitions. I described common mechanism how to inject prototype into singleton. To avoid bean definition hell, it might be better to use simple constructors in your code and don't use beans to create every object in your app.

Comment: It does not need to be implemented lookup-method here. This approach still does not solve the problem of passing of parameter to constructor. Because it is needed to call method of `BeanFactory` to create new beans, we don't get anything from creation of lookup-method

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a factory method:

```
public JButton createButton(String name) {
    (JButton)button = ctx.getBean(JButton.class);
    button.setName(name);
    return name;
}
```

So you can avoid "new" keyword and let spring everything create for you.

As an additional hint, you do not have to implement ApplicationContextAware, you can just autowire ApplicationContext